# Prove that the sequence converges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

$x_n = n - 3n^2$ as $x_n \to \infty$

Here is the theorem that I am supposed to use:

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers:

i) $x_n$ is said to diverges to $+\infty$ if and only if for each $M \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $x_n \gt M$

ii) the logic is similar for $-\infty$

My attempt:

Let $M$ be any real number which is a natural number then $N \gt$ max{m} implies for $n\gt N$ $$n(1-3n) \leq N(1-3N) \gt M$$

which approaches $\infty$

I feel like there are some logical connectives that are missing and the use of the definition may not be correct especially with the "max${M}"$

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you do or don't understand as I am distracted by the fact that you have a line of the form $a~\leq ~b~>~c$ which makes no sense to write, having mixed greater than signs with less than signs.  You also seem to have reached the conclusion that your sequence $n-3n^2$ approaches positive $\infty$ which is clearly wrong as the sequence doesn't even contain any positive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M>0$, take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $3N-1>M$. Then, if $n\geqslant N$, you have\begin{align}n-3n^2&=n(1-3n)\\&<1-3n\text{ (since $n\geqslant1$ and $1-3n<0$)}\\&<1-3N\\&<-M.\end{align}This proves that, by definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-3n^2=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \gt 1$.

$x_n =n-3n^2 <n-3n=-2n$;

Let $M >0$, $M$ real.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$n_0 \gt M/2$

For $n \ge n_0$

$x_n < -2n <-2n_0 < - M$.

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$x_n=n-3n^2=n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}-3\right)$$ this tends to $-\infty$